# How to implement CompareTo for arrays?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class

```
public class MinPQ<T> : IComparable<T>
{
    private T[] keys;
    ...
}
```

How to implement `CompareTo` method? I would like to do the following in my method

```
public void decreaseKey(int i, T key){
   if (keys[i].CompareTo(key) <= 0) {...} // or if(CompareTo(keys[i], key) <= 0)
}
```

Most of the time `T` will be `int` or `double`

Comment: Why would you implement CompareTo in `MinPQ` when you are comparing the objects inside the array? MinPQ should not be responsable imo. If `T` should implement `IComparable`, then perhaps it would be better to add the constraint: `public class MinPQ<T> where T : IComparable<T>`.

Comment: if you want to compare separate element by index with the element of another array you shouldn't implement `IComparable<T>` - `int` and `double` have already implemented this interface. Maybe you want to accept only comparable types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you mean how to declare the type `T` as comparable. If so, you can do it with the following generic constraint.

```
public class MinPQ<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    private T[] keys;
    ...
}
```